# removing the additional black background from returned youTube video images?

Tags: javascript, youtube

Im pulling back images from youTube images like http://img.youtube.com/vi/9KPCO5ENlmw/0.jpg and what I see in the image is that the top and bottom of the image has a lot of black, is there some kind of method to remove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to go by the color, the wideimage library  (GD based) has this implemented already. The method is called autoCrop, an online demonstration exists .

http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/wp-content/current/demo/index.php?demo=autoCrop&output=preset%20for%20demo&colors=255&dither=1&match_palette=1

Otherwise if you know the size of your image you can create a div with overflow hidden and calculate the real image.

The problem is that youtube crop automatically the image and insertblack, I think that there isn't a method inside youtube to retrieve the image without black bars

Answer (score 0):

YouTube offers images that don't have the 4:3 ratio black strips. To get a 16:9 video thumbnail with no black strips, try one of these:

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/mqdefault.jpg
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/maxresdefault.jpg
```

The first one `mqdefault` comes as a 320x180 pixel image.

The second one `maxresdefault` comes as a 1500x900 pixel image, so it would need resizing to use as a thumbnail. This is a nice image but it isn't always available. If the video is of a low quality (less than 720p I'd imagine, not exactly sure) then this 'maxresdefault' becomes unavailable. So never rely on it.